# PHP/MySQL - DATETIME NOT INSERTING PROPERLY

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

```
$date_orig = $dom->getElementById("Date")->nodeValue;
$date = date("Y-d-m H:m:s", strtotime($date_orig));
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO records (`date`) VALUES ('".$date."')";
```

`$date_orig` is in this format "12/31/2012 11:23:00 PM"

I know the correct format for mysql date time is `Y-d-m H:m:s`.. I can echo `$date` and it looks just fine. Why isn't this working?

Comment: It should be Year - Month - Date

Comment: check datatype of your column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong

```
$date = date("Y-d-m H:m:s", strtotime($date_orig));
```

You shud use 'i' for minutes not 'm'.  Also you are adding day before month. it should be Y-m-d instead o Y-d-m

change it to this

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date_orig));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your date value as standard date format and insert it as normal value..
you can use to store date as:

```
$date= date('YYYY-MM-DD',strtotime($date_orig));
```